# Can I replace the spring in a 2011 Rockshox Recon Silver TK?

Tags: fork, suspension

I have a second hand Rockshox Recon Silver TK (2011 I think). The spring is very soft and I would like to replace it with a stiffer one.

I asked my LBS, who said you couldn't replace the springs on cheaper Rockshox and offered to sell me a new fork. This has made me suspicious.

Is it possible to replace the spring? Are springs still available for this model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service manual for SRAM forks is [Here](https://www.sram.com/globalassets/document-hierarchy/spare-parts/spare-parts-catalog/2021-rockshox-spare-parts-catalog.pdf).

It has a note on the Recon TK

> 2. Use air spring kit to upgrade and change firmness in coil forks

So while it is not possible to get a firmer spring, it is theoretically possible to upgrade the fork to air, if you can find the part for your exact fork model and year.